# Link not showing correctly in email body

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to send an email that contains a link, but it is not working properly.

Here is what I have:

```
mail.Body = mail.Body + "<div>" + "<p><a href=" +
                        "http://serverName/projectName/controllerName/AllSummaries?yesterday=" +
                        DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ">Click here to go to " +
                        DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " summaries!</a></p>";

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

The result of this in the email is:

```
http://serverName/projectName/controllerName/AllSummaries?yesterday=04/04/2017
```

Shouldn't it be:

`Click here to go to 04/04/2017 summaries!`?

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

String Interpolation:

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
mail.Body += $"<div><p><a href='http://serverName/projectName/controllerName/AllSummaries?yesterday={date}'>Click here to go to {date} summaries</a></p></div>";
```

Result:

I am still seeing the full link.. not the `Click here to go to {date} summaries`

Same Result when using `String.Format`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you are wrapping your `href` attribute within quotes and have proper closing tags for each of your existing ones.

You may want to consider using the `String.Format()` method to handle this (or a newer approach like String Interpolation)

```
// Using String.Format()
mail.Body += String.Format("<div><p><a href='http://serverName/projectName/controllerName/AllSummaries?yesterday={0}'>Click here to go to {0} summaries</a></p></div>", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

// Using String.Interpolation
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
mail.Body += $"<div><p><a href='http://serverName/projectName/controllerName/AllSummaries?yesterday={date}'>Click here to go to {date} summaries</a></p></div>";
```

Comment: I did the string Interpolation, and it still results in the same link.  Strange.

Comment: fixed.. I was saving, but not rebuilding.. thank you!